# Craft Pro 3.1.33 - Download PDF in admin user profile

Tags: assets, pdf, preview

In Craft 3 Pro i need to download a PDF file that a template form submits to active user profile.

The PDF submits from the front and goes to the admin area under the user account profile.

The problem is that in the user account profile i can see the PDF but cannot download it or even preview it (shows a white thumbnail image with PDF written).

The only way i find to download the pdf is going to the assets section and find it among the other file assets. I do not want this.

Is there a way of adding a download button, or click in the pdf preview to download the pdf, in the user account profile in craft 3 admin backoffice?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only i way i found to solve this was to made my custom plugin for craft 3 CP.

I build my template scafold here:

https://pluginfactory.io/

Then installed it via composer and started coding to achieve what i want.

Job done.